# Unable to create a container (name "NAME” is already used by ID). with nerdctl

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, rancher, nerdctl

I am using `nerdctl` as docker desktop alternative

I am facing the following error while running `nerdctl compose up`

```
Unable to create a container (name "v2_mongo_1” is already used by ID"asdfasdfadfa"). with nerdctl
```

I have check with `nerdctl ps -a`, there are no containers running, so am not able to find out how to get rid of this error.

```
mongo:
    image: 'mongo:4.2.3-bionic'
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - ./mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
      - ./mongo-init-local-replicaset.sh:/etc/mongo-init-local-replicaset.sh:default
      - ./docker/mongo:/data/db
    entrypoint: ["mongod","-f","/etc/mongod.conf"]
    healthcheck:
      test:  ["CMD", "/etc/mongo-init-local-replicaset.sh"]
      start_period: 3s
```

Comment: Apparently you try to create 2nd container with the same name in the same pod somewhere on startup ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `nerdctl rm v2_mongo_1` first to remove the existing container.

Comment: In this case, the container doesn't show up when using any other `nerdctl` commands, so using `nerdctl rm <name>` just results in a `no such container <name>` error.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my answer here as I encountered something similar and had to piece together a solution. This post came up when I googled the problem.

The other answer from @vinod didn't work for me, as there *isn't* an existing container, and so I can't remove it!

There is a github issue that gives a particular file path to delete: https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl/issues/499

Doing this worked for me, but the filepath cited in that issue was not the same as my local lima+nerdctl setup.

For anyone else finding this issue, I suggest you try going into the following directory in your lima guest:

`~/.local/share/nerdctl/1935db59/names/default`

and deleting whatever file in there matches the name that is clashing (which would be `v2_mongo_1` for the OP.

Hope this helps.